# What's the logic behind yielding scrapy.http.Request?

Tags: python, scrapy

The code that I can't get to understand is from [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

From [one of the stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855) I can get a basic idea at what time the lines around `yield` keyword are executed. But the code above is too difficult for me because of its seemingly nested `yield`.

Can you explain the interaction between the two `yield` and the callback mechanism? Specifically, how are these lines triggered to execute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `yield` is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/2207154). 
Actually, in this case no need for `yield`. You can easy replace it by `return` and will get the same result. It's because `yield` should be used when you need to iterate over list of some elements. For example to parse all links from the page you can do following loop:

```
for link in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
    yeild Request(link, callback=self.parse2)
```

and your `parse2` method would be called for each link. Yielding is about returning multiple request or items in scrapy. There's no rocket science here.

Comment: So `Request` is designed to yield its callback when itself is yielded?

Comment: @lin yes, in my example callback will be called for each iteration. Each `parse2` call will contain their own response object